# How to bind a type's `__init__` or `__new__` to some other class instance?

Tags: python, binding, setattr

I was trying to set a type attribute to a class using the Python built-in `setattr`. I've declared `__new__` and `__init__` methods in the type to see what their parameters would be and surprisingly they're not being bound to receive the class instance. I've read the Python docs on `setattr` and descriptors and I've performed some tests in the interpreter and I haven't found a way to bind the type's `__new__` or `__init__` methods to the class instance.

This is the code fragment I've been toying with:

```py
T = type("T", (object,), {"__new__": lambda cls: print(f"T.__new__: {cls}") or object.__new__(cls), "__init__": lambda self: print(f"T.__init__: {self}")})

T()
# T.__new__: <class '__main__.T'>
# T.__init__: <__main__.T object at 0x7f970b667c10>
# <__main__.T object at 0x7f970b667c10>

class A:
    pass

setattr(A, "T", T)

A.T()
# T.__new__: <class '__main__.T'>
# T.__init__: <__main__.T object at 0x7f970b6675e0>
# <__main__.T object at 0x7f970b6675e0>

A().T()
# T.__new__: <class '__main__.T'>
# T.__init__: <__main__.T object at 0x7f970b667ee0>
# <__main__.T object at 0x7f970b667ee0>
```

Essentially I want to know how can I make T receive the instance of A in the `__new__` or `__init__` methods. I believe that I didn't fully understand how `setattr` actually works and I'm misusing it or the way to accomplish this behaviour is not related to `setattr` at all.

*PS.: Declaring T as a regular class changes nothing and declaring `T::__get__` changes nothing as well.*

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223254). You're asking about `setattr`, but your actual objective seems to be binding behavior for `A().T()` (you want the `T` class to get bound to the `A` instance it's being looked up in). Is that right? I don't want to dismiss `setattr` in the first paragraph of an answer that's about binding behavior if you *really do* to know about `setattr` in some kind of detail.

Comment: @Blckknght you're right, I'll rectify.

Comment: It works like *any other object*. A type having another type in it's class namespace does nothing special. What you desire is simply not going to happen automatically. You may be able to accomplish it by defining a metaclass that is a descriptor, but it's going to get into pretty arcane aspects about how/when descriptors gets used. It honestly doesn't seem like it is worth it. What is *the actually issue you are trying to solve?* Are you expecting it to work like a Java non-static nested class?

Comment: `setattr` isn't relevant here. `setattr(A, "T", T)` is *exactly* equivalent to `A.T = T`. Also, using the `type` constructor isn't really relevant. Again, it works the same way if you use a class definition statement.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I just want to have access to the `A` instance, `a`, in `T` initialization when calling `a.T()`, to avoid `a.T(a)`. It may not be worth it once I get to know how to accomplish that though I still want to know how to do that. Couldn't find it in the first page of Google so far.

Comment: @RodrigoMartinsdeOliveira right, might I suggest editing your question to empahsize that? The use of `setattr` is not really relevant. Neither is the use of `T = type(...)`. These two sort of obscure your main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setattr` function is just a way to programatically do what you could do with a normal assignment. Your call `setattr(A, "T", T)` is exactly the same as doing `A.T = T`. It doesn't help you achieve what you seem to want, which is for the class `T` to have binding behavior when looked up in `A` (or maybe in an `A` instance).

While you *could* make a metaclass that makes the `T` type you declare as an attribute of the `A` class a descriptor, a much simpler approach is probably to write a method of `A` that returns an instance of the `T` class without actually being the class itself.

```
class T:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class A:
    def make_T(self):
        return T(self)
```

Now you can do `A().make_T()` and you'll get a `T` instance that was passed the `A` instance as an argument to its `__init__` method. If you want to, you can even rename `make_T` to `T`, and it will *mostly* work like you intended with your nested classes. It's not quite the same, since you can't use `A.T` as a class in other contexts, like `isinstance` checks. Using a name like `make_T` is a little bit clearer that it's a factory method, not a class itself.

If you really do need to put the class `T` inside of `A`, here's the metaclass approach:

```
class BindingInnerClass(type):
    def __get__(cls, obj, owner=None):
        if obj is None:
            return cls

        class BoundSubclass(cls):
            if cls.__new__ is not object.__new__:
                def __new__(subcls, *args, **kwargs):
                    return super().__new__(subcls, obj, *args, **kwargs)

            if cls.__init__ is not object.__init__:
                def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    super().__init__(obj, *args, **kwargs)

        setattr(obj, cls.__name__,  BoundSubclass)
        return BoundSubclass

class A:
    class T(metaclass=BindingInnerClass):
        def __init__(self, a):  # the metaclass will also work if you define __new__
            self.a = a

a = A()
t = a.T()
print(a, t.a) # prints the same object twice
print(isinstance(t, a.T), isinstance(t, A.T), isinstance(t, A().T)) # True True False
```

That metaclass is a lot more complicated and subtle than code really should be if you want to be able to read and maintain it. It creates a subclass of `T` for each `A` instance you look the original class up on. That might be very confusing, in some situations (like the last `isinstance` check in the example code)!

Here are some of the subtleties: We need to be selective about which of `__init__` and `__new__` we create because if we unconditionally create both, we'll get errors if `T` doesn't define them both as taking `obj` as a positional argument. Using naive binding (the way methods do), you'd end up with a potentially infinite number of classes, since you'd create a new subclass for every lookup (`a.T` would be a different class each time). To avoid that, I cache the subclasses using `setattr` (bringing us back full circle!).

I'd strongly recommend against using this kind of design for any serious code. This class architecture really stinks of trying to force Python into a design that would fit more naturally in some other programming language, where inner classes are a normal thing. It's almost certainly unnecessary to design the classes this way, there's likely to be a slightly modified design that is much more natural to Python's class model. Do yourself (and anyone who ever needs to read your code in the future) a huge favor and figure out what that better design is, rather than using a metaclass monstrosity that will be very tricky to understand or modify.

Comment: The auxiliary method won't work for me since I do need the type T and not just an instance of it. I'll try using a metaclass for that, if I understood it correctly I should declare a metaclass for T which makes it a descriptor, is that so? Can you include an example for that in your answer?

Comment: Hmm, I actually started in on the metaclass approach, and it's actually quite a lot more complicated than I expected. The issue is that given `x = A()` and `y = A()`, you want `x.T` and `y.T` to be classes, but to bind their instances to the two different `A` instances when you call them. That's hard to do if they're the same type, you probably need them to both be separate subclasses of `T` (that is, `x.T != y.T`). Automatically creating subclasses of unknown other classes is very fussy. I'd really question whether this architecture is worth it in Python. There's surely an easier way.

Comment: I will move on with the simpler approach of setting both a factory method for `T` and the type `T` itself each to an attribute of `A`. A bit more context: I'm dynamically creating T from A and while I want to allow free access to `T` I want to provide an easy way (with a helper) to instantiate `T`. Hoped `T.__init__` could deal with the helping part but trying to set `__get__` attribute to `__new__` is not allowed by Python so I guess there is no way this binding will happen and it makes sense bc otherwise, it would be a mess for Python to pass the cls and the bound instance to `__new__`.

Comment: Ingenious approach with the nested metaclass! I agree with you on not using that in serious, sane code.